# Spring Integration. Пакетная запись JPA сущностей в БД

Tags: java, spring, spring-jpa, springbatch, spring-integration

В проекте на Spring Integration есть канал, в который поступают JPA сущности и записываются в БД при помощи jpa outbound channel adapter.
Но jpa outbound channel adapter пишет сущности в БД по одному, а это довольно медленно. Как можно организовать пакетную запись (batch) JPA сущностей в БД в проекте на Spring Integration?

```
    <integration:channel id="persistJpaChannel"/>
    <int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter
        channel="persistJpaChannel" persist-mode="PERSIST"
        entity-manager-factory="externalEntityManagerfactory">
        <int-jpa:transactional transaction-manager="txManager" />
    </int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в `int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter` атрибут `flush-size="100"`
Он определяет через сколько элементов будет вызван `entityManager.flush()`

Comment: А по умолчанию у него flush-size="1"?

Comment: Добавление этого параметра не сильно ускорило запись в БД.

Comment: `flush-size` имеет эффект только если `payload instanceof Iterable`, иначе записывается как есть. Попробуй `flush-size="0"` и вызывай `entityManager.flush()` самостоятельно, когда тебе удобно. (Очень тежело коментировать на русском: рассмотри вариант создавать вопросы на английском  :-))

Comment: @ArtemBilan int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter может принимать List из JPA сущностей?
Как вызывать entityManager.flush() самостоятельно?  Его же вызывает int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter?

Comment: Это верно, но согласно твоему вопросу речь не идет о `List`, так что твой вопрос не ясен. Если ты действительно имеешь дело с `List`, то автоматический `entityManager.flush()` в конце операции вполне тебе подходит. Иначе - только руками. В чем проблема заинжектить `EntityManager`  в какой-то сервис и вызвать его  `flush()`?